# AWS: Access S3 from Elastic beanstalk application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have a PHP application which takes inputs from users and writes them to files using normal file operations like `fopen, fwrite` etc. It works well on my server. If I migrate this whole code to Amazon's Cloud and use it's services, how do I map these file operations to corresponding operations on Beanstalk?

Will the file operations work as they are, without change?
If yes, where will these files be store?
 If no, what's the alternative?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: maybe this helps? github.com/nathanlenz/s3fs-on-aws-beanstalk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider looking into the [S3 Stream Wrapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html#creating-a-pre-signed-url) included with the official [AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php). Registering the stream wrapper allows you to work with the S3 using PHP's native file functions.

Answer (score -1):

You can mount a S3 bucket as a partition and work with S3 files as they where located on your server's HDD.

I'm the lead developer and maintainer of Open source project RioFS project: an userspace filesystem to mount Amazon S3 buckets. You can use our project to mount and operate with files using PHP or any other programming language.

Hope it helps !